# Sharing mutable objects between actors

Tags: java, akka, state, mutable

I have the following scenario

`Actor A` receives request and delegates the work to two child actors `ACtor b` and `Actor c` . Both these actors change the state of the object but the parent actor does not depend on the result of any of these actors

Is this an anti pattern? How is it possible to distribute the load without passing this object?

Comment: Child actor notifies its parent about changes in your "shared mutable" object. Thus, "mutable" has not actually has to be mutable

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Here is example in scala but the logic is the same

```
class ParentActorA extends Actor {
  val childActorB: ActorRef = _
  val childActorC: ActorRef = _

  def receive: Receive = {
     case r: Request =>
       childActorB ! Delegate(r)
       childActorC ! Delegate(r)
     case n: ChildNotification => //change local state based on this notification from child actor       
  }
}

class ChildActorA extends Actor {
   def receive: Receive = {
      case Delegate(r) => //do some work and notify parent with ChildNotification object
   }
}
```